# Show values that below the certain percentage within other label in pie chart

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am trying to create pie chart. This chart will have 18 different labels. Problem is that the values of some fields in the series are minuscule compared to other fields (see screenshot of chart below). I want to aggregate fields that are lower than certain percentage of the whole series. For instance, I want to display values of fields that below than 0.5% of total as others. Does Apex Chart library have built-in option for my problem? If not, Do I need to solve this with a workaround?

[Chart that being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4qR4.png)

I tried to find a built-in solution from Apex Charts library, but i couldn't find a answer in the documentation.

Comment: Apex Charts does not have a built-in option to aggregate data points below a certain percentage of the total value. However, you can use a workaround to achieve this by pre-processing your data before passing it to the chart. @Mehmet Emre Ast.

Comment: @DSDmark thanks, i preprocessed data as you mentioned.